# Cannot load 'path\tomcat\\conf\server.xml: for attribute "useBodyEncodingForURI" associated with an element type "Connector"

Tags: java-ee

Здравствуйте!

Java Web app, на IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5

Все работал нормально. Давно не трогал. А сегодня выдает ошибку:

Error running 'portal': Cannot load C:\Users\.IntelliJIdea2017.2\system\tomcat\conf\server.xml: Error on line 72: 
Open quote is expected for attribute "useBodyEncodingForURI" associated with an  element type  "Connector".

В чем причина?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину. Каким то чудесным образом в строке server.xml Tomcat :

< Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" useBodyEncodingForURI=”true” />

оказались не те кавычки:

useBodyEncodingForURI="true"

Поставил нормальные кавычки и все заработало!